# JMeter Summary report shows subsamplers

Tags: jmeter

When I run my test through JMeter Graphic User Interface, Summary report shows my steps, which are Transaction Controllers, just with parent sampler: [image] which is OK for me. But, when I open log file (*.jtl) in Summary report after test run, I see all samplers - parent sampler with subsamplers: [image] How I have to set configuration in such way that, when running test through CLI mode and open log file to see just parent samplers?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks JMeter issue, it worth reporting it via [JMeter Bugzilla](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html).

In the meantime you can consider the following options:

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation):

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false
   ```

   this way you will have only "top-level" SampleResults in the .csv file. See [Results file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) related properties to see what else you can amend.
2. [Generate HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_only) from the .csv file

   ```
   jmeter -g /path/to/testresults.csv -o /path/to/dashboard
   ```

   The dashboard will have the summary table without these extra subresults
3. Use [JMeter Plugins Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) to generate the CSV form of the Summary Report in command-line without having to open JMeter GUI, add Listener, etc

   ```
   ./JMeterPluginsCMD.sh --generate-csv /path/to/summary.csv --input-jtl /path/to/testresults.csv --plugin-type SynthesisReport
   ```

   in this case `summary.csv` will be in the format you're looking for.

   Both [JMeter Plugins Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) and [Synthesis Report](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SynthesisReport/) can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmitri T. This row 'jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false' resolved the problem.

Comment: it masked the problem as with this setting JMeter might fail to properly calculate the throughput